Выгрузка данных из одного справочника в другой
При изменении значение "Состояние" в справочнике "Абитуриенты", данные должны перенестись в справочник студенты


&НаКлиенте
Процедура СостояниеОбработкаВыбора(Элемент, ВыбранноеЗначение, ДополнительныеДанные, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    
    ИзмененныйАбитуриент = Объект.Состояние;
        
    Если ИзмененныйАбитуриент.Состояние = "Принят" Тогда
        
        
        НовыйСтудент = Справочники.Студенты.СоздатьЭлемент();

        НовыйСтудент.Наименование = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.Наименование;  
        НовыйСтудент.Пол = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.Пол;
        НовыйСтудент.ДатаРождения = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.ДатаРождения;     
        НовыйСтудент.КонтактныйТелефон = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.КонтактныйТелефон;
        НовыйСтудент.ЭлектронаяПочта = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.ЭлектронаяПочта;
        НовыйСтудент.Специальность = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.Специальность;


        НовыйСтудент.Записать();  
        
    КонецЕсли;
    
    
КонецПроцедуры





Ошибка
{Справочник.Абитуриенты.Форма.ФормаЭлемента.Форма(10,18)}: Переменная не определена (Справочники)
        НовыйСтудент = <<?>>Справочники.Студенты.СоздатьЭлемент(); (Проверка: Тонкий клиент)



Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO! Мы заметили, что ваш вопрос требует некоторых уточнений. Прежде чем его опубликовать, рекомендуем ознакомиться с справкой о том, как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Все манипуляции с объектом, производятся на сервере, нужно с клиента вызвать серверную процедуру и там уже можно создавать объект, записывать. Возможно нужно передать на сервер, аргументы в зависимости от задачи.
&НаКлиенте
Процедура СостояниеОбработкаВыбора(Элемент, ВыбранноеЗначение, ДополнительныеДанные, СтандартнаяОбработка)
  СостояниеОбработкаВыбораНаСервере();  
КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервере
Процедура СостояниеОбработкаВыбораНаСервере()
ИзмененныйАбитуриент = Объект.Состояние;
        
    Если ИзмененныйАбитуриент.Состояние = "Принят" Тогда
        
        
        НовыйСтудент = Справочники.Студенты.СоздатьЭлемент();

        НовыйСтудент.Наименование = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.Наименование;  
        НовыйСтудент.Пол = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.Пол;
        НовыйСтудент.ДатаРождения = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.ДатаРождения;     
        НовыйСтудент.КонтактныйТелефон = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.КонтактныйТелефон;
        НовыйСтудент.ЭлектронаяПочта = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.ЭлектронаяПочта;
        НовыйСтудент.Специальность = ИзмененныйАбитуриент.Специальность;


        НовыйСтудент.Записать();  
        
    КонецЕсли;
КонецПроцедуры  


Поле объекта не обнаружено (Состояние)
{Справочник.Абитуриенты.Форма.ФормаЭлемента.Форма(7)}: Если ИзмененныйАбитуриент.Состояние = "Принят" Тогда
{Справочник.Абитуриенты.Форма.ФормаЭлемента.Форма(26)}: СостояниеПриИзмененииНаСервере();

Да, нужно найти объект и реквизиты.
